# What is the length of relay race track?

Tags: logic, contest-math, education

**The relay track is divided into 4 stages.**

The sum of the first and second stages is 100m. The sum of the second and third stages is 200m. The sum of the third and fourth stages is 300m. The sum of the fourth and first stage is 400m.

What is the length of the whole route?

```
1 + 2 = 100
2 + 3 = 200
3 + 4 = 300
4 + 1 = 400
```

I was thinking about summing different parts. There are two possibilities:

```
1 + 2 = 100
3 + 4 = 300
```

So in total we have 400 m.

Or

```
4 + 1 = 400
2 + 3 = 200
```

We get 600m here. Is there two different answers or the way I think is wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is I can not find total length of full route - 1, 2, 3 and 4 stages.

Comment: The data is inconsistent for the reason you said.  Here is another inconsistent answer: add all four equations together and you get two tracks is 1000m so one track is 500m.

Comment: Thank you @Henry